# How can I start trading in cryptocurrency when none of the trading sites support the banks in my country?

Tags: money-transfer, cryptocurrency

I live in Jordan, and-unfortunately-none of the trading sites support banks in my country. So I can neither use CC, nor direct money transfer.

Do you happen to know a workaround for my situation?

Comment: Are you asking us to give you advice for illegal activities? We might disagree with your country’s laws, but I wouldn’t give you advice how to circumvent them.

Comment: https://www.coindesk.com/central-bank-jordan-blocks-financial-companies-bitcoin/ - This seems to be a regulatory prohibition against banks and money changers using cryptocurrency. This is different than cryptocurrency being illegal for private citizens to deal in.

Comment: Can you edit the question to clarify that it is not illegal but that your banks won't support these transactions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Bitcoin".

Comment: @RonJohn "Bitcoin" is not a close reason, and it is not automatically off-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious workaround is to have a bank account or credit card issued from a bank that will support these transactions. That bank may be outside of your own country.

This may add cost and hassle to get your money back into your local bank account from your other bank account or credit card.

You should ensure that you are not breaking any laws in your country by having this bank account or transacting in cryptocurrency. You should also ensure that you correctly report any income from trading for the tax laws and rules in both the country where the bank account exists and your own country.